# How to fix broken system of Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I was in the process of upgrading from 10.04 to 10.10 via the update manager. In the midst of the installation process, the system lost power.
Now when I boot, the login window shows nothing. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please add more information. Does Grub start? Gets the kernel loaded? gets initrd loaded? Does the system boot? Is there any hard disk activity? Can you ping the system although no login is possible?

Comment: Reboot the system, hold the <kbd>Esc</kbd> Key down as the system boots, at the GRUB menu choose "safe mode"?

Answer (score 1):

Boot a Live CD, chroot into the installed system and finish the upgrade. 
I guess this is just what the graphical installer of the 11.04 live cd does when you select the upgrade-option in the "select installation type" dialog.